# act.offensive.c: In function âdo_fireâ: act.offensive.c:631: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âabortâ

Tags: c, declaration

I'm rather new to coding but when compiling ( I use putty and SHH ) i receive this error

act.offensive.c:631: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âabortâ 
act.offensive.c:637: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âabortâ

On lines 631 and 637

CREATE (lodged->next, LODGED_OBJECT_INFO, 1);
CREATE (target->lodged, LODGED_OBJECT_INFO, 1);

I did a search for aaborta and abort through the files in the SRC (for the compile) directory and did not find a match anywhere to explain it or find the file to index it to.

I was wondering if someone might be able to help me

Comment: The function isn't `aaborta`. The `â` characters are the result of the compiler using a different character set from the terminal, really they're quotes. So the function with the problem is `abort`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try including `<stdlib.h>` in the file where the built-in function `abort` is declared.

The error message says about incompatible *implicit* declaration, so it might be that there's no explicit declaration anywhere in your code and the macro `CREATE` (I believe it's a macro?) tries to use it.

If that doesn't help, it'd be helpful if you could edit your question and describe what's `CREATE` in your code.

Comment: Hello, its working now! :) Thanky ou very much. The stlib resolved it